# Install kadm5 php extention

Tags: php, pecl, extension

System is:

- openSUSE Leap 42.2
- php 5.5.14-77.3.1

---

I want to install the kadm5 extention for php5 and have so far failed to do so.

As https://codex.wordpress.org/User:Hakre/HowTo_PECL_on_Opensuse suggests I've tried with:

```
pecl install kadm5-alpha
```

which throws:

```
downloading kadm5-0.2.3.tar ...
Starting to download kadm5-0.2.3.tar (105,984 bytes)
........done: 105,984 bytes
13 source files, building
running: phpize
Connot find config.m4.
Make sure you run '/usr/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

I also downloaded the files manually and tried it the way it is explained by http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.phpize.php, what results in phpize working just fine but then

```
./configure
```

throws:

```
configure: loading site script /usr/share/site/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php5 -I/usr/include/php5/main -I/usr/include/php5/TSRM -I/usr/include/php5/Zend -I/usr/include/php5/ext -I/usr/include/php5/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php5/extensions
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php5
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for kadm5 support... yes, shared
checking for kadm5 files in default path... not found
configure: error: Please reinstall the kadm5 distribution
```

So the question is how do I install kadm5?

Thanks in advance
G4

Comment: I figured out that the error message originates from the config.m4. It searches for the **kadm5/admin.h** file. But that file is nowhere found on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this.
The krb5-devel Package provides the needed admin.h Header which is needed to build the kadm5 extension.